# Need help how to use execute('scrollTo(0,500)') inside POM function, but it says execute is not a function

Tags: nightwatch

I am trying to create a function using `execute` to use inside POM

```
 ForthStCheck:function(){
        this.waitForElementPresent('body', 30000)
            . execute('scrollTo(0,500)')
```

Comment: browser.execute('scrollTo(0,500)') . --> WORKS but i need it inside POM

Answer (score 0):

.click('@AlternativeSt')
            .api.execute('scrollTo(0,500)')